# Why does Troi hear the melody during the TNG episode "Survivors"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In TNG Season 3, Episode 3 titled "The Survivors", Counselor Troi hears a repeated melody in her head that drives her almost to insanity. We (the audience) learn the source of the song relatively early in the episode.

> (the music box)

By the end of the episode, we've learned the secret of the survivors, and someone has removed the music from her mind.

> (Kevin Uxbridge, a Douwd - a previously unknown race with immense power)

**Why did she hear the music in the first place?**

Especially since the one who caused it was able to take it away so easily?

*(There may not be an actual confirmed answer, so I'll accept conjecture and opinion as long as it's derived from actual events in the episode or series)*

Comment: He's not unidentified. He's identified.

Comment: OP, it’s spelled “Douwd.” I hope you change it. Quick edits apparently can’t be made anymore, which is unfortunate, because spelling mistakes irk me.

Comment: Thanks @Bob! I hate them too :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Kevin put the music in her mind to distract Troi. The box wasn't the source of the music, merely the inspiration for it.

> **KEVIN:** *I've taken the music from her mind. She's alright now. She's sleeping. **She was beginning to sense who I really was.** I've been living as a human for over fifty years but I couldn't hide from her. She has suffered because of my pride and selfishness. It will not happen again.*